# How to run cmd.exe hidden in Inno Setup

Tags: command-line, inno-setup

I was wondering if there was any way to run the command prompt from Inno Setup's `Exec` function in a way which would hide the output from the user.  Currently I have the below function which I'd like to do this for.

```pascal
Exec(
    'cmd.exe',
    '/c ' + InstallPath + '\initdb ' + '-U postgres -A password -E utf8 --pwfile=' +
        InstallPath + '\password.txt -D ' + DataPath,
    '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I know you can add a flag to the `Run` section, but haven't really found anything analogous to that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to change the `SW_SHOW` to `SW_HIDE` to hide the command window.

For example:

```pascal
Exec(
    'cmd.exe',
    '/c ' + InstallPath + '\initdb ' + '-U postgres -A password -E utf8 --pwfile=' +
        InstallPath + '\password.txt -D ' + DataPath,
    '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

---

For those using `[Run]` section, see [How to run a CMD command without openning a new window in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44039720/850848).