# How to run a CMD command without openning a new window in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, cmd, inno-setup, windows-console

I am using Inno Setup installer to setup an installer file, that can invoke the .exe that I just installed through its scripting, and launch it right after installation, with the following command:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,3mtxmail}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser; \
    Parameters: "/b /k "" ""{app}\my.exe"" -c ""{app}\default.conf"" "" "
```

When `my.exe` is operating, it doesn't need any interface, and should only listen to any traffic on a specific port, and write that traffic info to a log file.

However, when I execute the installer and launched the program, it still brings up a new console window, which I think the `/b` should have prevented. I expect not to see this new console window, and actually don't see anything on the screen.

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx, the `/b` should be the flag that indicates not to open new windows for the command.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Is it a console or GUI application?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It is a console.

Comment: Only one question per post, please.  You are of course welcome to ask your new question, but please post it separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not look like you need the `cmd.exe` for anything. Run your application directly instead:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\my.exe"; Parameters: "-c ""{app}\default.conf""" \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,3mtxmail}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser;
```

---

Though if your application is a console application, it will open its own console. To prevent that, add [`runhidden` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runhidden).

You can actually use the `runhidden` flag to hide even the `cmd.exe` console window. But if you have no need for the `cmd.exe`, you should not use it.